# Improved / efficient code for multiple if - React Native

Tags: react-native, if-statement, coding-efficiency

I´m a technical project manager coordinating developers. My coding skills are limited and so I align with my devs on logical structure. For a mobile app (React Native to serve Android and iOS) we are currently developing *user current location* logic. Turned out we have specific Android and iOS settings, what may require native developmetn for location service handling.

I´m currently reviewing the following pseudocode and, besides others, concerned about the MULTIPLE IF statements and thinking if there is a more efficient way, as here we seem to jump into every IF, even when location is set already before.

I think there can be something like "until", "break" or similar .. and maybe relevant to consider the specific dev language, React Native in that case?

Any help, as pseudocode or if possible to make it specific already considering React Native, is very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
////Central Location Service to get current location.
var currentLocation;
var locationType

if Android {
    DEFINED_ACCURACY = QUALITY_BALANCED_POWER
} else id iOS {
    DEFINED_ACCURACY = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
}


DEFINED_DISTANCE = 3000

function startLocationService(){
    var locationservice = LocationService()
    locationservcie.accuracy = DEFINED_ACCURACY
    locationservcie.distance = DEFINED_DISTANCE
    locationservcie.startListnertoLocationUpdate() {
        cacheData(location, currentTime);
        currentLocation = location
    }
}

function getLocationFromLocationService() {
    if locationServcieEnabled == false
        return NULL;
    if locationPermissionGranted == false
        return NULL;
    return currentLocation;
     
}
function getCurrentLocation() {
    var lcoation = NULL;
    var accuracy = Not_defined;


    lcoation = getLocationFromLocationService() //GPS, network
    locationType = locationService
    
    if lcoation == NULL {
        locationdata == getLastKnownLocation()
        if locationdata.Age < DEFINED_DURATION {
            location = locationdata.location
            locationType = locationService
        }
    }
    if location == NULL {
        location == getCachedLocationWithin24Hour()
        locationType = locationService
    }
    if location == NULL {
        location = getLocationfromTelephony()
        locationType = other
    }
    if location == NULL {
        if permissionToUseBilling == false {
            askForPermissionToUseBilling()
        }
        location = getLocationFromBillimg()
        accuracy = other
    }
    if location == NULL {
        location = getLocationOfDEfaultCountry()
        accuracy = other
    }
    return location, Other
}
```

Comment: switch cases maybe

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use switches to cover different cases from javascript.
Probably your dev team knows, but did not want to bring it into pseudo code?

```
   const location = getLocationFromLocationService() ;
   switch (location) {
   case 'NULL':
   //DO SOMETHING WHEN NULL;
   break;
   case 'New York':
   // DO SOMETHING WHEN New York;
   // No break leads to run also into the next case
   case 'Bern':
   console.log('I love nice cities.');
   break;
   default:
   console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${location}.`);
}
```

Interestingly you seem to have multiple times the same if case?
Maybe you will to nest it or have to use a switch with multiple expressions.

> case ("Bern" && "ANOTHERExpression to be true"):

[Link to switch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Please don't underestimate your dev team. ;-)